# Initialize std::vector of std::unique_ptr with lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda, unique-ptr

Is it possible to initialize an `std::vector` in a single line using lambda functions?

I am using the following aliases:

```
using UI = std::unique_ptr<int>;
using VUI = std::vector<UI>;
```

So far, I am able to do the following:

```
UI init[] = { UI(new int(0)), UI(new int(0)), UI(new int(0)) };
VUI vec { std::make_move_iterator(std::begin(init)), std::make_move_iterator(std::end(init)) };

VUI vec;
for (unsigned i=0; i<3; ++i)
    vec.emplace_back(UI(new int(0)));
```

I would like to do something like this but in a single line, preferably using lambdas.

Comment: What's the purpose of the single line, other than obfuscating the readability of your code?

Comment: You can write every single imaginable construct in single line (except multiple macro directives, you can only have a single macro directive on a line).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
int main()
{
    using UI = std::unique_ptr<int>;
    using VUI = std::vector<UI>;

    VUI vec{ []()
             {
                 VUI v;
                 for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
                     v.emplace_back(new int(0));
                 return v;
             }()};
}
```

But why?

Comment: Is that a _single line_ as asked for?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It's a single statement. Remove the newline characters if it makes you feel better.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't ask that for my behalf.

Comment: I was curious as to whether it was possible and yes that covers it!